# Ajax & php: FormData object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some data to PHP via jQuery AJAX. It only works if I send the data like this:

```
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
   //processData: false,
   //contentType: false,
     url: 'productEdit.php',
     data: {'data_spa':arr, 'id': id, 'table': table_name, 'insert': values}
```

But whenever I try to send a **FormData()** object it stops working. However if I send just the **form_data** (uncommenting processData and contentType) it works:

```
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
processData: false,
contentType: false,
url: 'productEdit.php',
data: form_data
```

All I'm trying to do is send the values and the form_data as JSON, like this:

```
data: (form_data, {'data_spa':arr, 'id': id, 'table': table_name, 'insert': values})
```

And in PHP it should receive the data like this:

```
$arr = $_POST['data_spa'];
$image_file = $_FILES['file']['name']
```

By the way, I'm creating the FormData object like this:

```
var file_data = $('#imageProduct').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
```

I hope you can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var file_data = $('#imageProduct').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('data_spa':arr);
form_data.append('id': id);
form_data.append('table': table_name);
form_data.append('insert': values);
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this, it works partially, but **form_data.append('data_spa':arr);** doesn't send the hash at all. The **arr** variable is a hash, so it captures the values like this: arr['id_sub_category'] = subcategory; Where, in this example, **id_sub_category** is the column's name, so in PHP i can do something like this:

foreach($arr as $key => $val){ // Get columns name with its values            $cols[] = "$key='$val'";        }

It is done this way to dynamically store data no matter the number of columns, without repeating code.

Comment: Ok, I finally solve like this: **form_data.append('data_spa', JSON.stringify(arr));** and in PHP **$arr = json_decode($_POST['data_spa'],true);** And then I got my associative array back, Thank  you very much Gian.

Comment: try form_data.append('data_spa':arr.serializeArray());